# need to resize a control (UISlider) to fill all available UIToolbar space (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4, uitoolbar

I need to resize UISlider to fill all available UIToolbar space, and it must work under iOS 4.3 and iOS 5.0. (Well, I have something that works for 5.0, but for 4.3 it is still a puzzle.)

There is an UIToolbar whose buttons are configured dynamically, including buttons that appear only for landscape orientation. (The full set is specified in the Interface Builder and some of them are removed via `bar.items = filteredItems`) Between the buttons on the left and on the right, there is a slider (and a flexible space next to it).

I want the slider to fill all available space between the two groups of buttons (the left group and the right group).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I counted the width of all bar button items.

The main idea is that their order is not important and we can use an IBOutletCollection:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *allButtons;
```

and in the code that gets executed before orientation change:

```
const CGFloat leftOrRightMargin = 12; // measured on a screenshot
const CGFloat gapBetweenButtons = 10; // measured on a screenshot
const CGFloat experimentalCorrection = 6; // don't ask why

int totalNumberOfButtons = 0;
CGFloat totalWidthOfButtons = 0.0;
for (UIButton *b in allButtons) {
    if (b.superview) { // if it's visible
        totalNumberOfButtons++;
        totalWidthOfButtons += b.bounds.size.width;
    }
}
CGFloat occupiedSpace = experimentalCorrection
                      + 2 * leftOrRightMargin
                      // gaps: totalNumberOfButtons-1+1, the last one is for the slider
                      + totalNumberOfButtons * gapBetweenButtons
                      + totalWidthOfButtons;
// now, resize the slider control
```

after orientation change:

```
[myBar setNeedsLayout];
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this with a UISearchBar ... I guess you never found a slicker solution?

Comment: when I add my searchbar in IB it seems to resize itself with an orientation change. If I then set the items again on the toolbar with fewer items the searchbar doesn't resize but stays at the size it was before. Is frustrating.